# Issues to get Jquery JSON data in Codeigniator

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I have create a view

```
    $.getJSON("/admin/sync/sync_curl/4/whois",          
    function(data) {
        log("Who is onboard table has been updated with " + data + " records after " + modifiedSince);               
    });
```

in my controller I make a call to fetch some a json string from a remote server with a rest call and then update my local database - I only send back to my view how many records i have updated.

```
    function sync_curl($shipid, $table)  {  

        $this->load->model('whois/whois_m');

        $this->load->spark('curl/1.2.0');

        // Build remote URL            

        $remoteURL = 'http://192.201.00.22/api/1/';

        $remoteURL .= $table;

        $remoteURL .= '?API-KEY=xjkljioeo884444ssf'

        // Simple call to remote URL
        $result = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($remoteURL), true);  

        // count records
        $count = 0;            
        foreach ($result[$table] as $record) {
            $this->whois_m->update_insert($record);            
            $count++;
        }

       header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
       echo $count;           
    }
```

I can used the url in my view for $.getJSON = **"local/admin/sync/sync_curl/4/whois"** directly in my browser and I receive the number of records.

When I try to run this function from my view - I click a button to start the action - nothing happens I have debugged and i get no were - when i changed the $.getJSON request by adding **"http://"** like this

```
    $.getJSON("local/admin/sync/sync_curl/4/whois",
```

My question is why do I need to have the **"localhost"** - i want just to have **admin/sync/sync_curl/4/whois** - as I would need to deploy this over many different servers and the the request is always local?

Comment: You said "*when I changed the $.getJSON request by adding http*..", but your code snippet doesn't include `http`.  And I don't see `localhost` there either.  Please proofread your question and make sure you've included the relevant info (and btw, your server-side code is *not* relevant in this case, consider removing it).

Comment: What about using `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` to replace the `localhost`? Thus you can deploy it to many different servers.

Comment: thanks for the feedback - i used local instead of localhost as i could not post it with local.

Comment: I will try with <?php echo base_url(); ?> thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("<?php echo site_url('admin/sync/sync_curl/4/whois'); ?>"
```